# Add text/HTML before the end of the 'body' tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string (not [document object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)) which contains a whole HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css" style="display:none;">
            <!-- P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;} -->
        </style>
    </head>

    <body dir="ltr">
        Bla bla
    </body>
</html>
```

And some text or other HTML code, which I need to insert before end of the 'body' tag in the first HTML.

In which way is it better to do this?

- Convert the string to HTML?
- Insert text or HTML in it
- Convert the result to a string

Comment: What do you mean by *"Convert the string to HTML"*? HTML is text. Some DOM thingy?

Comment: Where is the string? Is it stored in a variable in JavaScript? Where does it come from? How is it called into existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newHTML = "<div><p>This is New Html</p></div>";
$("body").append(newHTML);
console.log($("body").html());
```

If you need to concatenate another string in your HTML, try this:

```
var firstString = "<div><p>This is a string</p></div>";
var secondString = "<p>This is another string</p>";
firstString += secondString;
console.log(firstString);
```

**Update**

```
 function AddHtml() {
    var firstString = "<body><div><p>This is a string</p></div></body>";
    var indexOfbody = firstString.indexOf("</body>");
    var Firsthalf = firstString.slice(0, indexOfbody);
    var middleHalf= "<div><p>This is another string</p></div>";
    var LastHalf = firstString.slice(indexOfbody);
    var FinalString = Firsthalf + middleHalf+ LastHalf;
    console.log(FinalString);
}
```

Comment: I have one string, which is HTML and I need to insert to it another string. There is nothing to do with current document

Comment: you mean you have to combine two HTML strings into one?

Comment: Please check my post. I just updated it. I  hope that is what you want. :-)

Comment: var firstString has <body> tag and I need to insert secondString before and of body tag

Comment: @Ted, Please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var htmlString = "<p>Hello, World!</P>";
$(document.body).append(htmlString);
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? The whole HTML document is in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').append('Some content <b>with HTML!</b>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Existing code here<br/>
```

Comment: But the OP said "not document object". The whole HTML document is in a string (though the whole question isn't very clear).